# JavaFX BorderPane - make borders visible

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, borderpane

Am developing an application in JavaFX. I use BorderPane to place various controls. In each region of BorderPane, I use either use HBox or VBox.

Now I wish to make the borders visible, so that each region can be separated by a line. Is there an option to make the borders of each region visible ?

If not possible, suggest me another way to separate each region of the BorderPane using lines or dotted lines ?

Comment: What does "visible independently" mean?

Comment: @jewelsea That means to make one, two or three borders visible at a time, instead of making all the borders visible.

Comment: still don't understand - what borders? Show a sketch or a SSCCE to illustrate what you mean

Comment: @kleopatra Hey don't think too much....Its simple. I just want to know whether it is possible to make the borders of the regions of the BorderPane visible.